# How to calculate standard deviation from matrix_stats on elasticsearch v5.x?

Tags: elasticsearch

When executing the below command:

```
"aggs": {
    "matrixstats": {
        "matrix_stats": {
            "fields": ["my_field"]
        }
    }
}
```

The return result just contains  values such as count, mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis, covariance, correlation.
I would like to get value of standard deviation, min, max... as well.
Can anyone help to resolve this point? An example will be helpful.
Thanks in advance..!